# Clicking the webelement in dropdown menu with Selenium / Java

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to fill a form to create an gmail account.

```
package seleniumpackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class HoverTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Utwórz konto")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]/div[2]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        // Neither this works
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=':5']/div")).click();

        // Nor that
        WebElement HoverMonth = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'goog-menuitem-content') and text()='Maj']"));
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(HoverMonth).perform();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        action.click(HoverMonth).perform();

    }
}
```

The problem is to perform a click on the month in drop down menu.

In second method driver correctly hovers over the specific month but it doesn't click it which results with "Miesiąc" instead of "Maj". Passing a xpath to specific month doesn't work neither.

Comment: have you tried CSS Selector?

Comment: have you tried `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'goog-menuitem-content') and text()='Maj']")).click()`

Comment: I found it's id which is ":5" - that didn't work.
I tried SIslam's advice but neither that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go along with Xpath.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class gmailSignup {
    @Test
    public void gmailCalendar(){
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Utwórz konto")).click();
        // Open the month select field
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]/div[2]")).click();
       // Select the fifth month = "Maj"
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='BirthMonth']/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]")).click();


       driver.quit();
       }
}
```

Comment: Still nothing. Funny thing, with thoose xpaths **mouse hover event** works but **clicking** doesn't.

Comment: Well that is funny. Here is the full code. I launch it from IntelliJ IDEA / Java bindings... and it works, as "Maj" is being selected...

Answer (score 0):

You have to click the Birthday dropdown first, then click the desired month. I just tried this code and it works.

```
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/b/0/SignUp?service=mail");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[title='Birthday']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id(":6")).click();
```

where ":6" is the 6th month.

Comment: It must be something with your environment. I just ran this code and it worked fine for me.